# How to separate particular field from a JSON response?

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I am trying to retrieve a list of custom objects using an HTTP Request inside the visualforce page. I am able to send the request properly and I am also getting the result properly. The json response I am getting is like this:

```
 ({DateOfBirth__c=1992-01-09, Id=a1A0U000001NOTtUAO, Name=If You Are Rh Negative, ResourceUrl__c=null/article/95319e3cf5eab5f9bb99010c2018c429/en/healthsheets-v1/if-you-are-rh-negative, attributes={type=MailHistory__c, url=/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/MailHistory__c/a1A0U000001NOTtUAO}}).
```

All I want is to take the `DateOfBirth__c` and assign it to a variable. For that, I used this code:

```
if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
        List<Object> objects = (List<Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
        for (Object obj: objects) {
            Map<String, Object> mapJson = (Map<String, Object>)obj;
            MailHistory__c mHistory = new MailHistory__c();
            mHistory.DateOfBirth__c = (Date)mapJson.get('DateOfBirth__c');
        }
    }
```

So, the problem is whenever I run this code, the page is asking for authentication. And I figured out that the problem is with this line `mHistory.DateOfBirth__c=(Date)mapJson.get('DateOfBirth__c');`. When I replace the `DateOfBirth__c` from `(Date)mapJson.get('DateOfBirth__c');` field with any other custom field, like, there is another field in this object called `ResourceUrl__c`, the code works fine. And I have checked many times, all the properties of  `DateOfBirth__c` and `ResourceUrl__c`are same and only their data type is different. So, what could be the problem with the `DateOfBirth__c` field? Or is there any other way to separate a particular field from the JSON response?

Answer (score 0):

The JSON.deserializeUntyped can't determine a Date from a String. Therefore, you'd have to `Date.valueOf(...)` (or DateTime) or `(Date)JSON.deserialize((String)obj.get('DateOfBirth__c'), Date.class);` (or DateTime) to get the value to a date. Consider using a typed deserialization instead:

```
MailHistory__c[] records = (MailHistory__c[])JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), List<MailHistory__c>.class);
```